# Sinon restore cannot read property 'restore' of undefined

Tags: sinon

I have the following code which I am using Sinon for

```
import React from 'react';
import { mount } from 'enzyme';
import sinon from 'sinon';
import { IncrementalSearch } from './IncrementalSearch';

describe('<IncrementalSearch />', () => {
afterEach(() => {
   this.constructorSpy.restore();
});

it('calls constructor', () => {
    this.constructorSpy = sinon.spy(IncrementalSearch, 'constructor');
    const wrapper = mount(<IncrementalSearch />);
    expect(IncrementalSearch.prototype.constructor.calledOnce).toEqual(true);
    // expect(1).toEqual(1);
});
```

});

Now when I run this I get the following error

```
  TypeError: Cannot read property 'restore' of undefined
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

You have two problems here.

1. The immediate problem of `this` referring to something else than what you believe it to.
2. You misunderstand what the `constructor` property refers to.

The `this` pointer in `afterEach` refers to another context (the outer `describe` context) than the `this` in the test. Generally, to make life simpler, avoid using `this` when not necessary and simply use normal variables.

To fix the first problem, let's just rework your example a bit:

```
import React from 'react';
import { mount } from 'enzyme';
import sinon from 'sinon';
import { IncrementalSearch } from './IncrementalSearch';

describe('<IncrementalSearch />', () => {
    let constructorSpy;

    afterEach(() => {
       constructorSpy.restore();
    });

    it('calls constructor', () => {
        constructorSpy = sinon.spy(IncrementalSearch, 'constructor');
        const wrapper = mount(<IncrementalSearch />);

        expect(IncrementalSearch.prototype.constructor.calledOnce).toEqual(true);
    });
});
```

**Your test will still fail, but for another reason**

You should [read this thread](https://github.com/sinonjs/sinon/issues/831#issuecomment-197094024) on the Sinon issue tracker, especially the discussion between me and *machineghost*. The quick summary in your regard is that you need to read up on how Javascript protypes actually work, as the `constructor` property does not have anything to do with the `constructor` *keyword* used in ES6 "classes." It refers to the function that created the object. Changing it after the fact, will not have any effect.

The *actual* constructor is the function ("class") you export from `./IncrementalSearch`. Just [see how babel transpiles it](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?babili=false&evaluate=true&lineWrap=false&presets=es2015%2Creact%2Cstage-2&targets=&browsers=&builtIns=false&debug=false&code_lz=FAYwNghgzlAECyBPAwgewLYAdUDsCmOALrAN7Cywi5SEBOAriIarQBQCUZFFhAFgJZQAdADNUqWAF5YAFgBMAbnKwAvsDVA). So, in essence, if you really want this test to pass, which has nothing to do with your code, but is just a check if React is actually calling your code (which you should really just trust it does...), it should suffice to wrap the function. I haven't tested this though, as this might fail due to the spy not calling the wrapped function with `new`.